# dynamically update textbox value from database when combobox value is changed

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Here is the situation. I have a drop down menu. The option sin  this drop down menu are being populated by fetching some values from the database. To do this following is what i have done.. :-

```
<select name="product_list" onchange="selectProduct(this.value)">
    <option value="none">Select one</option>
        <%
            List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
            DynamicCombo comboBox = new DynamicCombo();
            options = comboBox.generateComboBox();
            Collections.sort(options);
            int tempVar = 0;
            while (tempVar < options.size()) {
                out.print("<option value=\"");
                out.print(options.get(tempVar));
                out.print("\">");
                out.print(options.get(tempVar));
                out.print("</option>");
                tempVar++;
            }
        %>
</select>
```

DynamicCombo is a class that has a method called 'generateComboBox()'. This method simply returns an array list containing all the values that are fetched from the database, which is what i need to show in my drop down box in the front end (jsp page). On my jsp page i simply iterate through this list and print it as options appropriately.
This works absolutely fine.

Now i have another text box on my form, say 'textbox1'. Now the requirement is that this text box value should be updated depending on what the user has selected from the above drop down box.

So for example if the user selects 'prod1'(which is a primary key in the backend database table) option from the drop down box, then the corresponding value ( the product name) should be fetched from the database table and should be updated in the textbox named 'textbox1'.

The other thing is this entire thing is contained in a form which is supposed to be finally submitted to the servlet for further processing.

So how can i achieve this.

Comment: what are doing in onchange function selectProduct? i think you have to update the textbox in this function

Comment: ok i wrote that function to just try to get the value of the user selection. I don't mind updating the text box from within this function. But how do i take values from the backend to update and that too depending on user selection.

Comment: whenever user selects a value that selectProduct function is called and you will get the value selected

Comment: yeah true. the value will get selected. Now depending on this value i have to fetch other values from the database and update the texbox1 on the form with this fetched value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out the solution to my own problem. It might not be the most elegant way of doing it, but it does the job pretty well.

So as per my requirement, what i exactly wanted to do was.... insert a value (that will be fetched from the database) into a text box on my form depending on what the user chooses from the drop down box that is already present on my form.

To achieve this, i went about and thought if some how i could nest a form withing my main form, it'd solve my issue. But i discovered that nesting of forms is not allowed. So the next option i thought of was to some how submit the same form without the user clicking on the submit button and also handle it appropriately as an 'incomplete' submit (in the sense that the form is still to be submitted manually by the user by clicking on the submit button) on the server.

So i simply made use of the 'onChange' event of a drop down box. I created an additional hidden field on my form.I wrote a simple javascript function that would simply set the value of the hidden field to the string-"partial Submit" and would submit my main form (say named 'form1') as :-

```
document.getElementById("hidden_id").setAttribute("value","partial submit");
form1.submit;
```

The function that does the above will be called whenever (and everytime) the onchange event of the drop down box gets fired.

When the user finally clicks on the submit button on the form to submit the finally completed form, then another javascript function is called that simply sets the value of the hidden field on the form to the string, "final submit" and would submit the form as :-

```
document.getElementById("hidden_id").setAttribute("value","final submit");
form1.submit;
```

Now on my server, i checked for the value of this hidden field as :-

```
if(request.getParameter("hidden_id").equals("partial Submit"))
{
  // make a database connection, pass the value user selected from the drop down box
  // to a prepared statement that does the query for getting the 'productName' from 
  // the database, collect the returned string in a variable and set a 
  // request attribute with this returned value. This value can simply be used in the 
  // jsp to fill in the value part of the textbox1.
}
else
{
  if(request.getParameter("hidden_id").equals("final Submit"))
  {
   // do the rest of the final processing that needs to be done when user finally   
   // submits the completed form.
  }
  else
  {
     // throw an exception to take care of the possibility that the user might send 
     // in a 3rd value as a value for the hidden field.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent provided the code for `selectProduct(this.value)`  , i presume that it submits the jsp page as when you change the value in the drop down.

If that the case in the servelt, set the value that you want to show in jsp in request object

```
request.setAttribute("valuetodisplay" ,valuetodisplay);
```

and now in jsp

```
<input type="text" value ='<%= request.getAttribute("valuetodisplay")%>' />
```